# WP Learndash plugin, get course points of user from subsite

Tags: wordpress, points, learndash

I have a multisite setup of wordpress. I am using Learndash in subsite(xyz.com) and need to get the course points on my main site(abc.com).

I have a reward system in abc.com. When an end user buy some product, he will get 100 points.

On xyz.com I have Installed Learndash, if that user completes a course he will get 100 points and I need to add those course points in main site points. So it will display 200 points in his account.

How can I get the course points from xyz.com to abc.com?

I am using the multisite so the database is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$userID = get_current_user_id();
$blog_id = 0;
if (is_subdomain_install()) {
    // For subdomain installs
    $blog_id = get_blog_id_from_url($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
} else{
    // For subdirectory installs
    $blog_id = get_blog_id_from_url($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] , "/risconew/university/" );
    if (empty($blog_id)) {
        $blog_id = get_blog_id_from_url($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] , "/risco-university/" );
    }
}

global $wpdb;
$tablePrifix = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix($blog_id);
$totalPoints = array();
$activitytable =  $tablePrifix . "learndash_user_activity";
$postmetatable =  $tablePrifix . "postmeta";
$PostMetaArray = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT act.*,postmeta.* FROM $activitytable AS act JOIN $postmetatable AS postmeta ON act.post_id = postmeta.post_id WHERE act.activity_type = 'course' AND act.activity_status = 1 AND act.user_id = " . $userID);
foreach ($PostMetaArray as $PostMeta) {
    $postMetaValue = $PostMeta->meta_value;
    $postMetaValueUnserialize = unserialize($postMetaValue);
    $points = $postMetaValueUnserialize['sfwd-courses_course_points'];
    if (!empty($points)) {
        $totalPoints[] = (int) $points;
    }
}
$totalCoursePoints = array_sum($totalPoints);
echo 'Total Course Points: ' . $totalCoursePoints;
?>
```